# What does "kiss my half!" means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, pun

At the end of the movie *Mank*(2020), audio between a reporter and the real
Orson Welles was played

> [reporter] Anything you'd like to say to your coauthor, Mr.
> Mankiewicz?
>
> [real Orson Welles] I do have a message. You may tell him from
> me…Mank, you can **kiss my half**!

What does "kiss my half!" means ?

Comment: I guess it's similar to "kiss my ass". (Based on the fact that Welles wrote half of the script.) This isn't a common English expression though, and you're better asking on Movies and TV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the full real-world context (alluded to by the cited movie fragment) - [a letter from Orson Welles to Mankiewicz](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you%20can%20kiss%20my%20half%20i%20dare%22), apparently after they'd co-authored a script (written half each)...

> *Dear Mankie:
>
> Here's what I wanted to wire you after the Academy Dinner:
>
> **You can kiss my half**
>
> I dare to send it through the mails only now I find it possible to enclose a ready-made retort. I don't presume to write your jokes for you, but you ought to like this:
>
> Dear Orson:
>
> **You don't know your half from a whole in the ground***

Obviously ***half*** in both cases is a "wordplay replacement" for ***ass*** - the "standard" versions being...

> *He can [kiss my ass](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kiss%20someone%27s%20ass)*
> *He [doesn't know his ass from a hole in the ground](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+know+your+ass+from+a+hole+in+the+ground)*   (Welles's ***whole*** puns on ***hole + half***)

Both of those are essentially *American* expressions, but Brits often say *He* [*doesn't know his arse from his **elbow***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his%20ass%20from%20his%20elbow%2Chis%20arse%20from%20his%20elbow&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) for the second one.

---

TL;DR: The cited use of ***half*** instead of ***ass*** is just "one-off" context-dependent wordplay - *good* wordplay, but what a shame Welles couldn't have worked in [***half-assed**!*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105133/etymology-of-half-assed)

Comment: Brits would actually say 'He doesn't know his **arse** from his elbow.' Ass is very AmE, though we've picked it up from US TV over the past few decades.

Comment: I think what you mean is Brits would ***spell*** it like that! :) Most Brits aren't particularly "rhotic", so it's pronounced the same however it's written.

Comment: The American *ass* is very different from a British *arse* :)

Comment: No, because "arse" has the FATHER vowel, whereas "ass" (whether meaning 'donkey' or in the American sense) has the HAT vowel.

Comment: @ColinFine - yes, although curiously, posher Brits used to call a foolish person a 'silly ass' but pronounce 'ass' like 'arse'. One such was my music teacher at Alleyn's, 'Pop' Kennard. This used to make the boys giggle. Also some High Church Anglicans (and Catholics?) do the same with 'mass' (the rite).

Comment: @Mari-LouA - tell me about it, darling!

Comment: @ColinFine: I was gonna say "arse" has the BATH vowel, so Liverpudlians  whose ***bath*** rhymes with ***maths*** will get their ***arse** = posterior* mixed up with their ***ass** = donkey* as well as their elbow! (At least Southerners like me don't have that extra layer of confusion to worry about :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Quite. We Brits all have delightfully perky ***buns***, but Americans are ***lardasses*** :)

Comment: I'm from the North & am always telling my partner that glass & bath don't have an 'r' - but arse definitely does, no matter how you pronounce the others.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: I'm from the extremely non-rhotic ***Sarf London***, where we don't pronounce that /r/ even though it's invariably included in the written version (We *do* know the difference between our non-existent **r**'s and our various holes, wholes and elbows! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - did I ever tell you I grew up in Norwood Road, Herne Hill?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I don't think so. If you did, I either didn't notice or I plain forgot. I thought you were somewhere up in the Midlands.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it's not so much a pronounced 'r' as a long 'a'. I don't pronounce the actual 'r' either. Maybe I should spell it glahss,  bahth & ahss. ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - mother Old Kent Road, father Derbyshire, born in Camberwell, grew up in Herne Hill.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. There is a widespread misconception among (non-rhotic) BrE speakers that there is an "r" sound in (how they pronounce) words like "part".